# Why can't I construct a string with a NULL char* in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, why does the following code throw a runtime error? Could someone explain this for me?

```
char* p = NULL; 
string str(p);
```

I tried this in VS2013 and Codeblocks, but both got a runtime error.

Comment: It is specified by the C++ standard. Are you asking why that is? Probably because a null pointer isn't a valid string.

Comment: but the constructor is not like this: string(char* p)
{
if(!p)
{ m_p = (char*) malloc(1);
m_p[0] = '\0'; }
...
}

Comment: Yes, and? Just because you can make some code that does something when passes a null pointer doesn't mean it makes sense. I'm not down-voting BTW.

Comment: What's your question? The title seems to say the opposite of the body.

Comment: oh yes, sorry i just want to know why i can not construct a string with an empty char* in C++ .

Comment: What exactly are you expecting it to put in the std::string?
The constructor copies the nul terminated character string into the std::string, but you are not pointing to a string of any kind so what are you expecting to be the result?

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `string::string(const char *)` requires that the argument point to the first element of a null-terminated array of characters. You are violating that requirement.

For reference, [string.cons]:

> ```
> basic_string(const charT* s, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
> ```
>
> *Requires:* `s` points to an array of at least `traits::length(s) + 1` elements of `charT`.

(It is `traits::length(s)`) that requires null termination of the array, see  [char.traits.require].)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the string class expects a pointer to a valid string. And a null-pointer isn't. But the run-time library might or might not check whether the given pointer is null. So, in one environment the code might simply crash and in another the run-time library might handle the error in another way, for example by throwing an exception.

Note the by

```
char* p = NULL;
```

you have not created an empty string, but a pointer with a value of zero, thus pointing to an illegal address. If you wanted to create a pointer to an empty string you should have written:

```
char* p = "";
```

Comment: The situation is that i want to put the char* where p point into an vector<string> in an loop, but when p is NULL , the program crashed.  anyhow   thank you